# How to access module scope in module function

Tags: boost-python

I want to access the module scope in a c++ function.  `scope()` isn't doing what I want.

```cpp
void module_function()
{
    \\ Want to access module scope here
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(my_module)
{
    def("module_function", &module_function);

    scope().attr("my_attribute") = "foo";
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand it, `scope` is intended to be use in module initialization (that's what `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` macro ends up defining). Is [this](https://pastebin.com/1nskUhDY) something along the lines of what you want to do?